# Wave effect of NestedScrollView inside CoordinatorLayout is not working when scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I made a layout using `CoordinatorLayout` as a container and `NestedScrollView` to display my contents.

I used `NestedScrollView` to hide my toolbar when scrolling down, but the usual wave effect which should be shown below toolbar whenever I try to scroll and reach the limit of the layout is not working.

Here is the

[image: example].

How to make this effect? If I use normal `ScrollView`, this effect will be shown but I can not hide my toolbar.

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.dicoding.paul.moviecatalog.DetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tb_my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:title="Detail"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTheme.TitleText"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_detail_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is my detail content:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        //contents
        //contents
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: `reach the limit of the layout is not working.` Could you elaborate more? By a gif or  sth else? Thanks

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท Hello, i have edited my question for better context. Thank you.

Comment: Oh that wave which belongs **to Android itself**. How about adding `android:clipToPadding="false"` to `NestedScrollView` and removing     `android:orientation="vertical"`? Just a guess..

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท Still not working. Well, it's not a big deal but i am just curious. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Try using (true-false) `android:nestedScrollingEnabled` in `NestedScrollView`. However, that comes from Android Itself.

Comment: @Mohsen, `android:clipToPadding="false"` is working. I put it in wrong place. Silly me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

In your `NestedScollView`.